# Add additional tab after reviews

Tags: layout, tabs, product, magento2

I am trying to have a few more additional tabs added after the Reviews tab, though my tab keeps appearing as the first tab

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block after="reviews.tab" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="postage.tab" as="postage" template="product/view/postage.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Postage</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Magento 2.3.1 they added a slight change to the `product.info.details` block by changing it's class. `<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details"...>` This means that it takes a sort order argument to control the positioning of the tabs.
`<arguments><argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument></arguments>`
You would need to add the sort order for each extra tab you create in the `detailed_info` group.